# CSS linear-gradient background-position bug in Chrome

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm wondering if there is a workaround for linear-gradient background bug in Chrome.

On my last project I've used linear-gradient as background on buttons. On hover there was background-transition, which pushed a white backgroud and pulled a blue one in this place. Simple effect, achieved by setting background-size to 200% and then, on hover, by changing background-position.

In the code snippet below, at least on Chrome (in FF, Safari and IE there is no bug), you can see what I mean. This bug still exists and make blue part of the gradient visible (1px on the right side), while on hover this 1px is filled by the white part.

I observed that, e.g. when `text-transform: uppercase` isn't set, then there is no problem. On the other hand, using zoom tool in a browser, make on some breakpoints the gap visible and vice versa.

Could someone please explain to me this strange behaviour?

[image]

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #fff 50%, #003b7c 50%, #003b7c);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #003b7c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #003b7c;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: .25s ease-in;
}

button:active,
button:focus {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Example button</button>
```

Comment: see below answer. Can't explain why but I can fix it :)

Answer (score 8):

The reason is the gradient is repeated, and Chrome seems to render it differently (I haven't bothered to find out why).

To get rid of it, you simply need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #fff 50%, #003b7c 50%, #003b7c);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #003b7c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #003b7c;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: .25s ease-in;
}

button:active,
button:focus {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Example button</button>
```

Comment: I see now, that on the left side is visible a little bit of blue part of the gradient, because the border is wider than the right one. I've tried to set no-repeat property in my project CSS, it makes no difference though.

Comment: "(I haven't bothered to find out why)" You know how people like to dismiss IE bugs as "just the way IE is"? You can do pretty much the same here for Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Change to this:

```
background-size: 250% 100%;
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #fff 50%, #003b7c 50%, #003b7c);
  background-size: 250% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #003b7c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #003b7c;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: .25s ease-in;
}

button:active,
button:focus {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Example button</button>
```

Comment: By me setting bigger background-size makes the blue part unfortunately even wider than before.

Comment: @kwiat1990 what do you mean? I thought you were trying to fix the white gap? See my example (run the snippet), it does that.

Comment: I'm trying to fix gradient positioning, because in Chrome something makes it wrong calculated. When I make background-size bigger, let's say up to 250%, it makes the blue part of the gradient visible (and it shouldn't be visible, it should be only on hover). It depends also on button's text length (on my project I have a couple of characters more than here in my example)

Comment: By changing the `background-size`, you are also changing the animation. Try `background-size: 5000% 100%;` to make it obvious.

Comment: I've set a little bigger `backround-size` than 200% and at the same time added `background-repeat: no-repeat`. It seems that now it works.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. That one white pixel was driving me mad (because it was visible on some, but not all buttons with gradient).

Comment: @VDWWD No problem. Feel free to accept this as the correct answer :)

Comment: @MarkP I would if it was my question ;)